# Laravel on stripe webhook throwing 302 (redirecting to login page) even when the route is public

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

My code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY') );

        // This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
        $endpoint_secret = 'whsec_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event = null;

        try {
            $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
                $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
            );
        } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // Invalid payload
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
            // Invalid signature
            http_response_code(400);
            exit();
        }

        // Handle the event
        switch ($event->type) {
            case 'payment_intent.canceled':
                $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
                dd($paymentIntent);
            case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
                $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
            case 'payment_intent.requires_action':
                $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
            case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
                $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
            // ... handle other event types
            default:
                echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
        }

        http_response_code(200);
```

I am testing it on local and firing events from stripe cli, however, laravel is throwing 302 error. I have already placed it in public route, and could easily hit the endpoint by accessing in incongito. I have also tested it from postman,and from there too there is no issue on hitting the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the webhook from the CSRF verification.

should look like

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*'
    ];
}
```

and your web route look something like

```
Route::post('stripe/webhook', [StripeWebhookController::class, 'handleWebhook'])->name('cashier.webhook');
```